# Token not needed after authorizing once

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, jjwt

i am trying to implement token based authentication using JWT token. I am using JJWT library for that.

Here is my Security Configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //http.csrf().disable();

    String[] patterns = new String[] {
        "/login",
        "/bower_components/**/*",
        "/app/**/*",
        "/index.html",
        "/home.html",
        "/signin.html"
    };
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(patterns)
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**/*").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            .antMatchers("/*").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEndPoint)
            ;
}
```

I am using springboot.
I called this api in the following way to generate a token.

```
   curl -v -X POST "http://localhost:8080/login" -d '{"username":"greenrabbit948", "password":"celeste"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json"   | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 51
>
} [51 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 51 out of 51 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqd3QtZGVtbyIsImV4cCI6MTQ2Nzc2Njk3MSwiaXNzIjoiaW4uc2RxYWxpLmp3dCJ9.eu_OuBIkc4BfcTsTu4t_6TCwyLkH4HcuQzvWIMzNQYdxXiWA77SfvwCe4mdc7C17mXdtBAsvFGDj7A9fzI0M1w
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2016 06:02:51 GMT
{ [164 bytes data]
100   211    0   160  100    51  15071   4804 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16000
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{
  "username": "greenrabbit948",
  "name": {
    "title": "miss",
    "first": "dionaura",
    "last": "rodrigues"
  },
  "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/78.jpg"
}
```

Using the token i call the rest of my APIs, 
Like this

```
curl -i -X POST "http://localhost:8080/login" -d '{"username":"greenrabbit948", "password":"celeste"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJncmVlbnJhYmJpdDk0OCIsImV4cCI6MTQ2ODE0MDg1MiwiaXNzIjoiaW4uc2RxYWxpLmp3dCJ9.t9pqrOmYfaVkzuAQgo4D4VbN2PibQuHPuPA6RKYU-keTzbFAX58l77hQTc4Cq28HpjFOeiDvNpNEgilNHFOfVA
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 10 Jul 2016 06:54:12 GMT

{"username":"greenrabbit948","name":{"title":"miss","first":"dionaura","last":"rodrigues"},"thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/78.jpg"}

$ curl -s "http://localhost:8080/profile/details/yellowfrog347" --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJncmVlbnJhYmJpdDk0OCIsImV4cCI6MTQ2ODE0MDg1MiwiaXNzIjoiaW4uc2RxYWxpLmp3dCJ9.t9pqrOmYfaVkzuAQgo4D4VbN2PibQuHPuPA6RKYU-keTzbFAX58l77hQTc4Cq28HpjFOeiDvNpNEgilNHFOfVA" | jq .
{
  "picture": {
    "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/71.jpg",
    "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/71.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/71.jpg"
  },
  "name": {
    "title": "ms",
    "first": "sofia",
    "last": "hansen"
  },
  "email": "sofia.hansen@example.com",
  "username": "yellowfrog347"
}
```

Now whenever i call the same API which i have called before again without the Token, the data is shown. How can i stop this from happening? How to make the token compulsory so that the data is shown only when the token is present? 
**This happened when i used POSTMAN to call the APIs.**

Comment: Show implementation of jwtAuthFilter and jwtAuthEndPoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write function gettoken() which get the token.If token available return true otherwise false.hope you will get answer.

Answer (score 0):

In-order to achieve this, you need implement an authorization framework like OAuth2 and add the following annotation

```
  @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and #oauth2.hasScope('read')")
```

This will make sure only if the valid token is passed, client is able to access the service.